# Bootstrap combined icons not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I used before bootstrap and the icons works fine.
Today I used bootstrap-combined.min.css and the icons are not working !!!

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    ...
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-beach-umbrella"></span>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

in fact bootstrap 2.3 works with Icon glyphs http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons

So here is how it works;

```
<i class="icon-star icon-black"> </i>
<i class=" icon-ok-sign icon-black"></i>
<i class=" icon-ok icon-success"></i>
```